# AVCaptureDevice doesnt find any device

Tags: objective-c, macos, avfoundation

This line of code is the problem I got today (macOS app):

```
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

After I update Xcode, the system is alway got me empty ***devices*** array.

The thing is, the old projects(created before the update) work as expected.

What's going on here...?

Does anyone has the same problem?

**------------UPDATE------------**

I found this not just happened to my mac,
also on the company's.

And it does affect my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found the answer...

Target Settings / Capabilities / App sandbox / Hardware

[image]

Comment: AHA! Thank you! Note that “microphone” is what give you permissions for audio inputs; if only “camera” is checked, you’ll still get an empty list for `AVCaptureDevice.devices(for: .audio)`.

Answer (score 0):

This problem only happens on the Mac OS 10.13, Mac OS 10.12 is normal. I have the same problem， and there's no solution yet. AVCaptureDevice not found video device, i think it's apple that added permissions on the camera on 10.13.